# Google Analytics 4 - Event issues with item lists

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've been working on a GA4 integration ([GA4 API link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#begin_checkout)) on a website and I'm running into a few issues. The main one is that any request containing an item list doesn't show up in the debug view unless the item list is less than ~8 items.

I have read about a maximum event size, which in cases like *view_item_list* is not an issue because I can batch send them over. However, when it's something like the *purchase*, *view_cart*, or *begin_checkout* event I'm not sure if batch sending 5 items at a time, multiple times, is the best way (or the proper way) to do it. Does anyone know how it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. I was going through the process of setting up GA4 on a new site. Everything was working apart from no ecommerce data in the "lists" array was present in the reports. Going back through the docs - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#purchase - I noticed I'd missed the required variable of "item_name", I'd only included "item_id" - it's not something highlighted as missing in the debug mode!